# How to incorporate all the four orientation in Navigation Controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have Tab Bar with four Navigation View Controllers for each tab. 
In one Tab when a row is selected I display the First Photo from a array of photos. This Present controller is a navigation controller and I have a button which calls the next view controller which shows the album.

My prob is when the user shifts the orientation and its not reflected in the screen. I have tried shoulAutorotateToInterrfaceOrientation method and also I have called this function in each of the navigation controllers which my tab bar buttons would call.

Kindly help me I am struck up on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that **every** view controller in your hierarchy supports the orientation you need.
You can cut your tabbar down to a single tab and make sure that your view controller (Present?) returns YES to shouldAutorotate to check.